# Understanding this string format in Java for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Looking at this solution to an answer that was made for an EditText field in Android Studio, I am wondering what this string means and how I can break it down to understand and interpret the parts that I need.

I have referred this:[Android Money Input with fixed decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013795/android-money-input-with-fixed-decimal)

I pulled this from Zds and Ninjasense's answer

`if(!s.toString().matches("^\\$(\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?$"))`

What I'm trying to figure out is how to remove the $ sign that is attached to the EditText so that I can use the number and make some calculations to it.

The whole code I'm currently using in my project is:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
        int before, int count) {
    if(!s.toString().matches("^\\$(\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?$"))
    {
        String userInput= ""+s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
        StringBuilder cashAmountBuilder = new StringBuilder(userInput);

        while (cashAmountBuilder.length() > 3 && cashAmountBuilder.charAt(0) == '0') {
            cashAmountBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
        }
        while (cashAmountBuilder.length() < 3) {
            cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '0');
        }
        cashAmountBuilder.insert(cashAmountBuilder.length()-2, '.');
        cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '$');

        cashAmountEdit.setText(cashAmountBuilder.toString());
        cashAmountEdit.setTextKeepState(cashAmountBuilder.toString());
        Selection.setSelection(cashAmountEdit.getText(), cashAmountBuilder.toString().length());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5E%5C%5C%24(%5C%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D(%5C%5C%2C%5C%5Cd%7B3%7D)*%7C(%5C%5Cd%2B))(%5C%5C.%5C%5Cd%7B2%7D)%3F%24) for visualizing the regular expression in your string.

The check mainly relies on digits `\d’ to be found a fixed`{3}`or ranged`{1,3}`or unlimited`+`number of times, allowing`,`and`.` to be preseent at specific locations.

[image: regexvisual]